# PHP Script for Imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

can anybody recommend a script which creates Thumbnails with imagemagick? All I could found were too old. It has to run with php5 and on a newer linux server.

It is important, that it uses imagemagick and not GD Lib. I already know timthumb, but it uses GD lib.

Comment: Were you wanting to use the ImageMagick extension? I have code that calls ImageMagick binaries.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Imagemagick thumbnail generation with php - using -crop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679092/imagemagick-thumbnail-generation-with-php-using-crop)